# Indexing into 2d numpy arrays with vector

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an *m*-by-*n* sized numpy array `a`, and a 1D array `v` of length *m*, with each element of `v` being a number between *0* and *n-1* (i.e., `v` is an array of indices). I would like to combine these to produce an array of length *n*, where the first entry is `a[0, v[0]]`, the second entry is `a[1, v[1]]` and so on. Obviously, the command `a[:, v]` doesn't quite do what I want (although it was my first guess). This could easily be done with a for loop, but I'm wondering if there's a more proper numpy way of accomplishing this.

Comment: Does `a[np.arange(n), v]` do what you want?

Comment: Yes! Thank you, should have thought of that.